# ExcelDataReader C# library 'Invalid file signature' error while reading the source raw .xls file locally after saving it from FTP Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, console-application, exceldatareader

Recently I was trying to build an app that can read excel files. But just after I select the .xls file I get an error saying this:(i am trying to  read the source raw .xls file locally after saving it from  FTP Server)

> e.Message = "Invalid file signature."  at line  using (var reader = GetExcelReader(stream, file))

NOTE : Yes those .xls files are completely opening in miscrosoft excel as well in wps office but when i  open those source .xls files in the ftp server and again those as save as .xls put it again in ftp server it works pefectly and even my ExcelDataReader library is readding it properly.   i Mean why there is a need to again saving as .xls to get it read through ExcelDataReader library . Are those soursr .xls files corrupt? but why those opening perfeclty in my system

My Code :

```
            using ExcelDataReader;
            var latestFiles = GetLatestXlsxFilesFromFtp(ftpServerUrl, ftpUsername, ftpPassword, folderPath);

            // Reading XLS files and updating the database
            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var fileTuple in latestFiles)
                    {
                        string file = fileTuple.Item1;
                        int associatedValue = fileTuple.Item2;

                        using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
                        {
                            var ftpUri = new Uri(new Uri(ftpServerUrl), folderPath + file);
                            var localFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.ToString());

                            ftpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
                            ftpClient.DownloadFile(ftpUri, localFilePath);

                            
                            using (var stream = File.Open(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"File Length: {stream.Length} bytes");

                                
                                //getting error here going into ctach block  e.Message = "Invalid file signature."  
                                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                                {
                                    var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
                                    DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

                                    Type modelType = GetModelTypeFromFile(file);
                                    var dynamicDbSet = dbContext.Set(modelType);
                                    bool skipFirstRow = true;

                                    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                                    {
                                        if (skipFirstRow)
                                        {
                                            skipFirstRow = false;
                                            continue; // Skip the first row
                                        }
                                        var record = Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);

                                        MapPropertiesFromExcelRow(row, modelType, record, dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList());

                                        SetPropertyValues(record, "SourceFile", file);
                                        SetPropertyValues(record, "SourceFileId", associatedValue);

                                        dynamicDbSet.Add(record);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                   dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

//Ignore brackets here i havent closed brackets perfectly here but those are done in my code ..;)

Comment: Can you open that file with Excel ? ExcelDataReader can't handle corrupt files or fakes. Some lazy developers fake Excel generation by generating a CSV file or HTML table with a fake extension and content type

Comment: Yes those .xsl files are completely opening in miscrosoft excel as well in wps office but when i  open those source .xls files and save as .xsl it works pefectly and even my ExcelDataReader library is readding it properly.   i Mean why there is a need to again saving as .xsl to get it read through ExcelDataReader library . Are those files corrupt? but why those opening perfeclty in my system

Comment: Check what the files actually contain. It could still be a fake. `XLS` (not xsl) is a binary format. Excel won't be fooled by the fake extension of a CSV or HTML file and *import* the text using the user's locale settings. When you save the file again though, you're saving a proper `xls` or `xlsx` file

Comment: The `xlsx` format used by everyone for the last 17 years is also binary, a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files. You don't need Excel to create it. There are libraries that generate real `xlsx` files in all languages, even Javascript. That's why it's unusual that those files have an `xls` extension. There are libraries that generate `xls` as well but this often has quirks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  btw all the .xls whereever i used word .xsl typing mistake anyways How to check those raw source .xls i am getting in the ftp server are fack or not?? i mean they are opening properly as well my client is pressurizing me that those are correct .xls files i mean how can i check any method/? those are real or fack?

Comment: @HansPassant how to select those files with explorer and where is the option to unblock them??

Comment: @HansPassant got u but  there is no option/popup showing when right clicking on the file properties